# kendo grid cancelChanges issue

Tags: javascript, user-interface, kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid

I am working on a web application using kendo grid(Angular JS). I should call `grid.saveChanges()` after every delete or insert operation. But in a special scenario such as

1. Insert a record and call saveChanges
2. Then delete the same record and call saveChanges
3. Then call the call grid.cancelChanges()

Normally it goes back to last `saveChanges` state but in my case it is showing the deleted row. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution.My issue is related to unique id.After saving the data i have changed the id of grid.dataSource.data() item.Because of that, the mapping between grid.dataSource._pristineData and grid.dataSource._data is broken.So my solution is change the id of grid.dataSource._pristineData also.Now its working.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried what you say in this demo: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing but it works correctly.

Maybe it only works when you call `saveChanges()` manually. Data to restore when you're calling `cancelChanges()` is stored in `_pristineData` property so try this workaround:

```
var grid= $("#YourGrid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.saveChanges();
grid.dataSource._pristineData = grid.dataSource._data;
```

Comment: i think that issue is related to grid.addRow().i have setting an id manually(grid.dataSource._data[grid.dataSource._data.length - 1].id = 0;).Is that make any problem for cancelChanges().

Comment: So when you remove line that you say, what id do you have in dataSource for added row? And is cancelChanges() starts to works correctly?

Comment: i had change my code like you said but after using code,if i made any change in grid it also affection grid.dataSource._pristineData without calling savechanges().More specifically if any change done in grid.dataSource._data it also affecting grid.dataSource._pristineData

Comment: oData Service is used to bind

Comment: Actually the real issue is not updating _pristineData when i call grid.saveChanges().But manual updation is not a correct fix because the type of both are different.